# Edit responses in Sharepoint 2016 Discussion Board

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, discussion-board

I have a discussion board that is created in a SharePoint 2016 onprem version.  Is it possible to allow someone to edit the reply's to the topics in the Discussion board - if so, how do you set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a reply from other user, you need to have at least design permission.